# Using/link static c++ library config4cpp

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I have extracted config4cpp into my projects directory under lib/config4cpp. I have ran the make file in lib/config4cpp.

I have added this include at the top of my projects cpp file

```
#include "lib/config4cpp/include/config4cpp/Configuration.h"
```

I have this line in my make file

```
g++ -L./lib -c queue.cpp -lcurl -lconfig4cpp
```

I am getting this error

```
g++    -c -o queue.o queue.cpp
In file included from queue.cpp:4:0:
lib/config4cpp/include/config4cpp/Configuration.h:35:34: fatal error: config4cpp/namespace.h: No such file or directory
 #include <config4cpp/namespace.h>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'queue.o' failed
make: *** [queue.o] Error 1
```

So it looks like its finding the Configuration.h file but then one of its other headers cant be found.

I have also tried

```
g++ -I"lib/config4cpp/include/" -c queue.cpp
```

And changed the header include to

```
#include <config4cpp/Configuration.h>
```

But I get the same error where it cant find the namespace.h file

This seems to be some thing related to being run from inside my make file.

```
output: main.o queue.o
    g++ main.o queue.o -o"bin/behavior"

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

message.o: queue.cpp
    g++ -c queue.cpp -L"./lib" -lconfig4cpp -I"./lib/config4cpp/include"

clean:
    rm *.o bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you have not given the -I argument to g++ so the following happens :

You give an absolute path to the header that you want to use. This header is now "located" inside you local folder (the one where you .cpp files are). When it tries to include "config4cpp/namespace.h" it looks inside the current folder. But you don't have a "config4cpp/namespace.h" file locally.

What you need to do is add :

`-I"lib/config4cpp/include/"`

As an argument to g++ with the following folder structure :

```
$BASE_DIR
    |-- config_test.cpp
    |
    |--lib
    |   |-- config4cpp.a
    |   | 
    |   |-- config4cpp 
    |   |           |-- include 
    |   |           |       |-- config4cpp 
    |   |           |       |           |-- Configuration.h 
    |   |           |       |           |-- namespace.h 
    |   |           |       |           |-- ConfigurationException.h
```

Comment: I went ahead and adjusted the -I flag to this. g++ -I"lib/config4cpp/include/" -c queue.cpp I still get this error lib/config4cpp/include/config4cpp/Configuration.h:35:34: fatal error: config4cpp/namespace.h: No such file or directory
 #include <config4cpp/namespace.h>

Comment: I've recreated your setup on my machine and it compiles perfectly. Here's my command : `g++ config_test.cpp -o config_test -L"./lib" -lconfig4cpp -I"./lib/config4cpp/include"`

Comment: i notice your command is missing the -c perhaps thats where mine is having issues.

Comment: I went ahead and gave this a shot but still no luck. Could you post your directory tree please. I feel like maybe I'm not placing the config4cpp files in the correct locations.

Comment: I've edited my answer with my directory tree. Also, do you need to create the .o file? I can't test the command with the -c argument currently since I'm at work

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm honestly not sure. It was my understanding that its best to make object files and then compile only the object files that have changed to save time when compiling.

Comment: I did find out this has some thing to do with my make file. If I run this outside my make file it works fine.

 g++ -c queue.cpp -L"./lib" -lconfig4cpp -I"./lib/config4cpp/include"

I have edited my question to include my make file